# How do I branch an existing branch in GitHub with Git?

Tags: git

I need to branch off a branch from a repository on GitHub, and then clone it to my computer. I have editing permissions.

For example, I contribute to this repository, called **johndoe/example**

- **johndoe/example** has a branch called **hello-world**
- I want to make a branch, **my-program**, based off the
  **hello-world**
- I want to do this locally.

Is this possible? If yes, how would I accomplish this?
If not, does that mean I have to branch it online and then clone later?

*Extra note*: I have some experience with GitHub, however, I am completely unexperience with Git. I am using the *NIX Git client on terminal.

Thanks!

Comment: You should checkout the [git doc](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging). You can use the `git branch` command.

Comment: *If not, does that mean I have to branch it online and then clone later?* - that is basically what you said you want to do in your first sentence

Answer (score 0):

In order, you have to:

```
- clone the online repo under your user namespace (github online features)
- clone your copy locally on your machine (`git clone ...`)
- checkout to the target branch (`git checkout ...`)
- create the new branch (`git checkout -b your_branch_name`)
```

This way is fine if you want to push back to the upstream from your copy of the repo, of course.

Answer (score 0):

1. First clone that project using `git clone <UrlOfProject>`
2. Check current branch by `git branch`. Current will be highlighted there.
3. If you are on `hello-world` then its ok otherwise switch to `hello-world` branch by command `git checkout hello-world`.
4. Now create new branch `git checkout -b my-program`.

To push that branch to repo, so that it will be visible over git ui in your repository:

`git push origin my-program`

In case if you don't find `hello-world` branch in your repo but it exists in online repo then execute this command first:

`git fetch --all`

It will pull all the branches to your local repo and then you can switch to any branch.

- Note `git fetch -all` is only required if you have an old cloned project. In case of latest clone you will find all the remote (online) branches in your local repository.

To check the branches in your local repo, issue command
`git branch`